# Android Studio terminal: adb is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: android-studio, adb

I tried to run an ADB command in the Android Studio terminal.  However I got the following error:

> adb is not recognized as an internal or external command

First I turned on ADB integration under `Tools > Android` menu.  Then I tried adding the `platform-tools` folder to a `Path` variable under `Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Path Variables` to no success. (I restarted AS after the change as you would a shell.)

**I know an easy fix would be to change my OS path variable, but I would like to avoid doing that.**  So the question becomes: is there any way to get Android Studio to recognize the command in it's terminal via the settings?

Note and opinion: This happens out of a fresh install of 3.0.1.  It seems a little silly to me if the software installs the SDK & tools that it would not have the commands working out of the box in the terminal.

Answer (score 20):

## Option 1

• Create a new file, copy paste these 2 lines:

```
PATH %PATH%;C:\Users\Example\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
cmd /k "cls"
```

> The path to the adb.exe is just an example. You have to find the correct path first, and use that instead of `C:\Users\Example\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`.

• Save the file with `.bat` extension, e.g. `cmdWithAutoUpdatedTempPath.bat`.
• Move the file where you want, e.g. `C:\Users\Example\AppData\Local\Android`.
• In Android Studio, go to `File` ▸ `Settings...` ▸ `Tools` ▸ `Terminal` and set the `Shell path` to `C:\Users\Example\AppData\Local\Android\cmdWithAutoUpdatedTempPath.bat`

> The name of the file and the path to it is just an example. You have to use the values from the previous two steps, instead of `C:\Users\Example\AppData\Local\Android\cmdWithAutoUpdatedTempPath.bat`.

## Option 2

In Android Studio, go to `File` ▸ `Settings...` ▸ `Tools` ▸ `Terminal` and set the `Start directory` to `C:\Users\Example\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`

> The path to the adb.exe is just an example. You have to find the correct path first, and use that instead of `C:\Users\Example\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`.

## Option 3

Update the path variable by using this command in the terminal, each time a new session is created:
`PATH %PATH%;C:\Users\Example\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`

> The path to the adb.exe is just an example. You have to find the correct path first, and use that instead of `C:\Users\Example\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`.

Comment: Tested in Android Studio 3.3.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: I have not tested this with spaces or special characters in paths.

Comment: Source of the path modifying technique: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31165218/1293492

Comment: Tested with Android Studio 4.1.0 on Windows 10. Unfortunately no success.

Answer (score 18):

The adb tool is located at

```
C:\Users\<YOUR PC USER NAME>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
```

On a windows system to access adb from anywhere (android studio,vscode,cmd etc) you need to add this path to the environment variable of your system.
for this

1. search environment variables
2. go to user variables section and edit path
3. add new path under key **PATH** and paste the above path

reopen the application (android studio/cmd/vscode) where you want to access adb, and try typing adb in the cmd ,you will have access to all the adb features.

Answer (score 6):

**on windows:**

If you have installed the software in its default folder, please follow the instructions below:

type:

```
cd C:\Users\<YOUR PC USER NAME>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
```

**YOUR PC USER NAME** - is your pc user name (without <> )

after that, please connect device and try adb by typing:

```
adb devices
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: "is there any way to get Android Studio to recognize the command in it's terminal **via the settings**".

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Windows 10, then go to Environmental Variables, Click on New

A new Window will open which will have two fields

- Variable Name
- Variable Value

Variable Name: Path

Variable Value: C:\Users<Your PC name>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

Hit on Ok then Restart Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

- ***For Connect wireless Android Device then follow this simple steps:***

  **Step 1:**

  Attach Android Mobile Device **with Cable**.

  and make sure mobile and computer **must be in Same Network**.

  **Step 2:**

  Open **Android Studio** and open **TERMINAL** phase in it. (which is located at left bottom).

  [image]

  **Step 3:**

  Provide path of **SDK location**.

  ```
    Ex:   C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>
  ```

  **Step 4:**

  Provide ADB Connection command:

  ```
   -->  adb tcpip 5555

     ex: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools> adb tcpip 5555 [Press Enter Button]
  ```

  if all aboves step is properly executed then you got Output like:

  [image]

  **Step 5:**

  Here, got your mobile IP address.

  (we got this if mobile device connected via WIFI and make sure computer connected same WIFI )

  and at last make device connection wireless so put this command:

  ```
   -->  adb connect 192.168.1.5

  ex: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools> adb connect 192.168.1.5 [Press Enter Button]
  ```

  and the final ouput:

  ```
  connected to 192.168.1.5:5555
  ```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows 10 or 11

Search Environment Variables

You will System property dialog

1. Select **Environment Variables** describe in **Step 1** [Environment
   Variables Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O26Ko.png)
2. Now Select **Path** describe in **Step 2** [Path Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ao93S.png)
3. Edit this [edit screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECuVE.png)
4. Click new and add address `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools` to your adb executable file [copy past address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNCsk.png)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem

I set global environment variable with platform-tools and then adb commands working in cmd ***but not in android studio terminal*** then I ***`set the environment variable for android studio`*** also with the following path

`File` →`Setting` →`Tools` →`Terminal` and now here set `Environment variables` in `Project Settings` by click on Right side icon in Environment variable edit text box.
Click on + icon and add Name Path followed with adb path with platform-tools path in values eg.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `env variable` set up and you can see that `cmd` finds `adb` and even see in `Task Manager` that `adb` is running but `Android Studio` still refuses to "find" it - just `restart` your computer... so stupid but works. Don't know why restarting Android Studio does not help.