# adb not work in android studio ,'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

i try use adb , i put my adb in  a PATH environment variable , and i run my app and navigate it to home screen ,adb work in cmd on my computer but it not work in terminal in android studio

in cmd it's work:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iDTh.png)

in terminal android studio:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfBdF.png)

i connect android studio to my device with android 11

in the seconed picture i Mistak in taking a photo it's adb instead ad

Comment: In the second picture the command not working is "ad" not "adb"

Comment: Hundreds of questions were asked about it. Please do research. Sample : https://stackoverflow.com/a/71680361/5595926

Comment: @HocineB sorry i take picture to another line ,so i write adb and it's not work